# is there any way for me to know if a file has been modified?

Tags: c#, filesystems

I am making a program that detects if a file has been modified. but the file is not from me. I wanna know if it is possible to know if the files I'm getting were already modified or not.

Is there a way for me to know that? I've tried the creation date and date modified but sometimes when I modify a file their values will be the same.

P.S. I don't have the original file. I wanna know if it is possible to know if the I'm getting were unchanged before i get it.

Comment: [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If you need to know whether the content of the file has changed, perform a hash comparison.

Comment: from what i know, FileSystemWatcher monitors if the file is being modified while my program is running. but what I need is for me to know if the file has been modified before i got it. thanks

Comment: What you mean by **file has been modified before i got it**? Is it received over network or from some other application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question has a few issues, as there are multiple ways to answer this.

1) If the question is, "I have received a file (that previously was not on the computer/network/location), and want to know if it has been modified...", then the answer is - no, because you're looking at a just a chunk of bits, then all of those bits are subject to being modified and adjusted in any way the sender wants - timestamps, file-status indicators (For instance, the 'archive' tag on Windows systems, or structured metadata on newer file systems) or anything else about that file can be set to what they want.

2) If the question is, "I have a file (on the local network or file-system that I can 'poke' every so often, or locally on the drive that I can 'poke' every so often) and I want to know if it has been modified *between the times my application has run*", then probably the easiest way to do this is to store a computed hash of that file (As answered by @Albireo).

3) If the question is, "I have a file (on the local network or file-system) and I want to know if it was modified *prior to any running of my application*", then you're looking at something that may or may not be possible, and will not be possible in a completely reliable way - having some understanding of the underlying structure and what you're expecting in that file will be necessary, and you'd be better off updating your question with more details of what the file consists of and why you're looking for changes programatically so that we can determine the best way of doing this.

Comment: thanks. i not a native english speaker. sorry. but yes, no. 1 completely describes my question. thanks for the answer.

Comment: Not a problem, glad I can help you figure things out :-)

Answer (score 1):

The following example creates a FileSystemWatcher to watch the directory specified at run time. The component is set to watch for changes in LastWrite and LastAccess time, the creation, deletion, or renaming of text files in the directory. If a file is changed, created, or deleted, the path to the file prints to the console. When a file is renamed, the old and new paths print to the console.
Use the System.Diagnostics and System.IO namespaces for this example.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Permissions;

public class Watcher
{

    public static void Main()
    {
    Run();

    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
    public static void Run()
    {
        string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        // If a directory is not specified, exit program.
        if(args.Length != 2)
        {
            // Display the proper way to call the program.
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: Watcher.exe (directory)");
            return;
        }

        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = args[1];
        /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
           the renaming of files or directories. */
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
           | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        // Only watch text files.
        watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

        // Add event handlers.
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        // Wait for the user to quit the program.
        Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
        while(Console.Read()!='q');
    }

    // Define the event handlers.
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
       Console.WriteLine("File: " +  e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
    }

    private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
        Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
    }
}
```

Reference: [Microsoft MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: my program is not designed to run all the time but will want to know if the file has been modified/changed before i get it. and i don't have the original  file so I cant compare their hashes. 
is this even possible? 
+1 to this for future reference. thanks. :)

Comment: You can save a copy of the file. So when you run your program you compare the content from the copy and the file you just opened. 

Example: log.txt and lastLog.txt - lastLog.txt is created everytime you read your log.txt. Next time you open log.txt you compare the content with lastLog.txt(which has the last content of log.txt).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if *the content* of a file changed, compute its hash:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

using (HashAlgorithmalgorithm = new .SHA512Managed())
{
    using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(@"path", FileMode.Open))
    {
        byte[] hash = algorithm.ComputeHash(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Persist the hash as you like on the first run, then recompute it and match it upon the saved value. If they are different, the file changed.